# Prevent form from being submitted and preserve data using Javascript onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms

So I have my form setup like this:

```
<form id="form" name='form' method="post" action="#" onsubmit="validate(this)">
```

and I have the following function to validate the form, but the problem is, when the validation fails, the form gets reset and thus you have to retype all the information. Although from what I've read having return false; in the validation function should prevent this, so what am I doing wrong?

```
var error = false;
var errors = [];

function validate(form)
{
    var name = form.inputname.value;
    var phone = form.inputphone.value;
    var email = form.inputemail.value;
    var make = form.inputmake.value;
    var model = form.inputmodel.value;
    var month = form.month.value;
    var day = form.day.value;

    if(!name || !phone || !email || !make || !model || !day || !month)
    {
        alert("Please complete the form");
        errors[errors.length] = "Incomplete Form\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (month < 1 || month > 12 || day < 1 || day > 30) {
        alert("Please enter valid Month/Day in format 1-12/1-30 ");
        document.getElementById("month").focus();
        errors[errors.length] = "Invalid Date\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    }
    else if (errors.length == 0)
    {
        window.location.href("reserved300771292.aspx");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @OJay Now it's not getting to the window.location.href part, but the validation is working perfectly, thank you

Comment: Thanks @OJay - that worked - if you post it as an answer - I'll select it as right!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly although your function is correctly returning true or false depending on your requirement, you are not returning it to the `onsubmit`, so your form onsubmit should read

```
onsubmit="return validate(this)"
```

secondly you may experience an interesting bug due to the `errors[]` being global. If the first form validation fails, then every subsequent form submit will fail also (even if it is valid) as you are not clearing the `errors` array. Declare the `errors[]` variable inside the  `validate` function.

Also I'm not sure the exact behavior you will get tring to redirect the browser in the validate function. This may stop the form from submitting (i.e. the data collected on the form will not be posted) or the redirect will not work. Personally I wouldn't try this approach, redirect on the server side if everything works the way it should, as it is best practice to validate server side and client side